# When iam trying to simulate in modelsim there is no obejcts

Tags: verilog, modelsim

```
module alu64bit_test;
// Put your code here
// ------------------
reg [63:0] a;
reg [63:0] b;
reg cin;
reg [1:0] op;
wire [63:0] s;
wire cout;
// End of your code
alu64bit alu2(
.a(a),
.b(b),
.cin(cin),
.op({op[1],op[0]}),
.s(s),
.cout(cout)
);
initial begin
{a}=0;
{b}=0;
{b}=~b;
cin =0;
op[0]=1;
op[1]=0;
end 


initial begin
#2000 a[0]=1;
//#2000 cin =~cin;
end
endmodule
```

here is the code, I am trying to simulate this test and no objects are appearing in the wave window,the another tests are working very well

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons the objects are invisible, is because the tool optimizes. You can avoid this by forcing no optimization while loading the code. The command (or option) varies based on your tool version. I used questasim 10.7b on the above code to turn off optimization and all objects were visible. The vsim command I used is,

`vsim -voptargs=+acc alu64bit_test`